# Send a text file from URL directly into a scanner

Tags: java, download, java.util.scanner

I am using java and currently, I can download a text file from the internet, read that file, then send that file into a `Scanner`. Is it possible to skip writing it to the harddrive and send it straight into the scanner? I tried changing the code some, but it didn't work.

```
URL link = new URL("http://shayconcepts.com/programming/ComicDownloader/version.txt");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(link.openStream());//Gets the html page
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("version.txt");//Creates the output name of the output file to be saved to the computer
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
fos.close();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("version.txt"));
```

Comment: Yes. Have you looked at the [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? It's all there. Check out the 3rd constructor which takes an InputStream. URL's can be opened as streams -- check out the [URL API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. Just do exactly like you said: feed the from the URL obtained input stream straight into the scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(link.openStream());
```

It has namely also a [constructor taking an input stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29). It accepts by the way the [charset as 2nd argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), you might want to make use of it if the text file is possibly in a different character encoding than the platform default one, otherwise you might risk [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(link.openStream(), "UTF-8");
```